# Kali linux booting issue from usb on asus x205ta

Tags: boot, usb, kali-linux

I just bought Asus eeebook x205ta and I want to put Kali Linux on it. I have Kali Linux 2.0 ISO and extracted it using universal bootloader and tried to boot it from bios. It won't boot to Linux and continues to boot to Windows 10. I checked with my other laptop hp246, it booted fine without any issues. I also tried creating `/EFI/BOOT` and putting some files that I searched through google but I'm still not getting it to boot to Linux.

Comment: Is secure boot off?

Comment: yes , the first thing I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Kali on my x205ta, granted with a few issues I had to research, but it worked. Even though it's a x64 proc, the EFI runs x86, which could be an issue if you haven't checked that out. I used Linux Live, and set up boot-usb. Hope that helps a little. It's not detecting my eth card so I will be looking into that after I get the system up and running.

Comment: Your answer does not provide a solution for OP